# JQuery: Fade In Only Specific Element (IE and Opera)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, opera

I'm facing a bit of a jQuery conundrum, and I'd appreciate someone helping me to solve it.

I want to fade in a web page, using jQuery, after all the text and images have loaded. So I set body style inline as "display:none" and then fade in the body using this basic snippet:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
      $('body').fadeIn(300);
}); 
</script>
```

This achieves exactly what I want in Firefox, Safari and Chrome. However, Internet Explorer and Opera present a challenge: when the body fades in, all the elements of the JQuery gallery, included in the page, appear simultaneously, instead of rotating, as they do in "normal" browsers.

I'm posting the entire gallery script here:

```
    /* Gallery */
jQuery.fn.gallery = function(_options){
    // defaults options 
    var _options = jQuery.extend({
        duration: 600,
        autoSlide: false,
        slideElement: 1,
        effect: false,
        fadeEl: 'ul',
        switcher: 'ul > li',
        disableBtn: false,
        next: 'a.link-next, a.btn-next, a.next',
        prev: 'a.link-prev, a.btn-prev, a.prev',
        circle: true
    },_options);

    return this.each(function(){
        var _hold = $(this);
        if (!_options.effect) var _speed = _options.duration;
        else var _speed = $.browser.msie ? 0 : _options.duration;
        var _timer = _options.autoSlide;
        var _sliderEl = _options.slideElement;
        var _wrap = _hold.find(_options.fadeEl);
        var _el = _hold.find(_options.switcher);
        var _next = _hold.find(_options.next);
        var _prev = _hold.find(_options.prev);
        var _count = _el.index(_el.filter(':last'));
        var _w = _el.outerWidth(true);
        var _wrapHolderW = Math.ceil(_wrap.parent().width()/_w);
        if (((_wrapHolderW-1)*_w + _w/2) > _wrap.parent().width()) _wrapHolderW--;
        if (_timer) var _t;
        var _active = _el.index(_el.filter('.active:eq(0)'));
        if (_active < 0) _active = 0;
        var _last = _active;
        if (!_options.effect) var rew = _count - _wrapHolderW + 1;
        else var rew = _count;

        if (!_options.effect) _wrap.css({marginLeft: -(_w * _active)});
        else {
            _wrap.css({opacity: 0}).removeClass('active').eq(_active).addClass('active').css({opacity: 1}).css('opacity', 'auto');
            _el.removeClass('active').eq(_active).addClass('active');
        }
        if (_options.disableBtn) {
            if (_count < _wrapHolderW) _next.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
            _prev.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
        }

        function fadeElement(){
            _wrap.eq(_last).animate({opacity:0}, {queue:false, duration: _speed});
            _wrap.removeClass('active').eq(_active).addClass('active').animate({
                opacity:1
            }, {queue:false, duration: _speed, complete: function(){
                $(this).css('opacity','auto');
            }});
            _el.removeClass('active').eq(_active).addClass('active');
            _last = _active;
        }
        function scrollEl(){
            _wrap.animate({marginLeft: -(_w * _active)}, {queue:false, duration: _speed});
        }
        function toPrepare(){
            if ((_active == rew) && _options.circle) _active = -_sliderEl;
            for (var i = 0; i < _sliderEl; i++){
                _active++;
                if (_active > rew) {
                    _active--;
                    if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _next.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
                }
            };
            if (_active == rew) if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _next.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
            if (!_options.effect) scrollEl();
            else fadeElement();
        }
        function runTimer(){
            _t = setInterval(function(){
                toPrepare();
            }, _timer);
        }
        _next.click(function(){
            if(_t) clearTimeout(_t);
            if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _prev.removeClass(_options.disableBtn);
            toPrepare();
            return false;
        });
        _prev.click(function(){
            if(_t) clearTimeout(_t);
            if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _next.removeClass(_options.disableBtn);
            if ((_active == 0) && _options.circle) _active = rew + _sliderEl;
            for (var i = 0; i < _sliderEl; i++){
                _active--;
                if (_active < 0) {
                    _active++;
                    if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _prev.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
                }
            };
            if (_active == 0) if (_options.disableBtn &&(_count > _wrapHolderW)) _prev.addClass(_options.disableBtn);
            if (!_options.effect) scrollEl();
            else fadeElement();
            return false;
        });
        if (_options.effect) _el.click(function(){
            _active = _el.index($(this));
            if(_t) clearTimeout(_t);
            fadeElement();
            return false;
        });
        if (_timer) runTimer();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div#gallery').gallery({
        duration: 2000,
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeEl: 'ul.gall-inner > li',
        next: 'a#next-btn',
        prev: 'a#prev-btn',
        autoSlide: 6000,
        switcher: '.brands-list ul > li'
    });
});
```

Could some knowledgeable person please help me to find a solution or a workaround? I'd be truly grateful!

Comment: Are you saying that without the `$('body').fadeIn(300);` it works fine in IE and Opera?

Comment: Yes! It's exactly as you're saying: the gallery works fine in all browsers, until I add the fade-in snippet, at which point it just kinda exposes itself in IE and Opera.

Comment: Have you tried placing the gallery call (`$('div#gallery').gallery({...`) inside the `$(window).load(function() {` instead of inside the `$(document).ready(function(){`?

Comment: Trying that, thank you, please give me a minute...

Comment: That, for some reason, resulted in blank page. Please take a look at the link I added in the main body of the question. But I have a feeling what you're suggesting is a correct direction, j08691. Any additional ideas?

Comment: @mrtsherman – Do I understand correctly that I should try to place the last snippet from the external file, starting with $('div#gallery') in a place of [gallerycode]?

Comment: are u getting any error in the console

Comment: @ Arun – only a couple of them, related to CSS hacks. Nothing on JS.